# vb.net making an audit trail and retrieving the values

Tags: vb.net

I'm making an audit trail in vb.net with sql developer/Oracle Server

When I build the solution I get the error "argument not specified for parameter" of the 5 values

any help would be appreciated

Here's the code

```
Public Sub UserLog(ByVal Userlevel As String, ByVal FirstName As String,
                ByVal LastName As String, ByVal Time As Integer,
                ByVal Action As String)
    Try
        Dim queryLog As String = "INSERT * TBL_LOG where USERLEVEL = (USERLEVEL,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,TIME,ACTION) VALUES ( '" & Userlevel & "', '" & FirstName & "', '" & LastName & "', '" & Time & "', '" & Action & "') "

        Dim connStr As String = ConstantsPub.connectionStr
        Dim query As String = queryLog
        Dim conn As New OracleConnection(connStr)
        Dim da As OracleDataAdapter = New OracleDataAdapter
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        conn.ConnectionString = connStr
        conn.Open()
        da.SelectCommand = New OracleCommand(query, conn)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: That's the oddest looking `INSERT` statement I've ever seen.  Is that valid PL/SQL ??

Comment: i dont know literally, I thought I'd use function but I thought I need values to return so i used sub, any help you can give me about the code?

Comment: If you don't even know the difference between `VB` and `PL/SQL` you're in more trouble than I can help you with.

Comment: You are going to want to close and dispose of those connections... or better yet use `Using` to make sure you don't leak connections.

Answer (score 0):

Your INSERT statement isn't correct; it should be formatted like this:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
```

However, if you're wanting to insert values into the TBL_LOG table from another table, you need to use an INSERT INTO SELECT statement, which is formatted like this:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column_name(s)) SELECT column_name(s) FROM table1;
```